# ffmpeg transcode to youtube live bad video container

Tags: nginx, video, ffmpeg, youtube, live-streaming

I've been attempting to transcode a stream produced by obs studio to my nginx server and send it off to youtube. Now I've made it work with twitch and I know these settings are actually transcoding it mostly correctly and is viewable. The problem being that youtube live picks it up as Bad video settings and tells me to change the current video container format. The other side effect that is probly unrelated is the stream looks really poorly on youtube. Looks like it was streamed at a poor bitrate and stuff but the real problem is the bad video settings error.

The ffmpeg command being used is as follows

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/Private/Private1 -vb 6000k -minrate 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -preset faster -r 50 -g 100 -keyint_min 50 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1 -sws_flags lanczos -tune film -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -f flv -threads 6 -strict normal  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{key}
```

I've tried with different framerates and been googling for awhile and found nothing or interpreted everything wrongly. Either way I would be very happy for some help here.

**System info.**

- OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
- Ram: 10gb
- Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T
- GPU: Geforce GT 520

**Internet.**

- Upload 15mbit
- Download 150mbit

If you need any more info I will gladly send it. Thanks for reading.

**Edit 1**

After some googling about what I'm doing wrong I decided to try and change stuff slightly and came up with this command

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost/(app)/(key) -c:v libx264 -r 50 -g 100 -keyint_min 100 -x264opts "keyint=100:min-keyint=100:no-scenecut" -sws_flags lanczos -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast -vb 6000K -minrate 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -s 1280x720 -tune film,zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -c:a copy -ac 1 -strict normal rtmp://(output site)/(output app)/(output key)
```

which as of my current testing seems to at least have a healthy stream for longer than 2 minutes if i only output to youtube live directly. Ive found output to my nginx server then youtube live breaks things.

my nginx rtmp settings are on this link https://pastebin.com/siE99Tv8

**Edit 2**

If I push the stream to a site like restream to stream it to youtube then it seems to be working. tested for 25 minutes with no change of them saying bad video container or anything. So I'm going to say nginx is partly to blame in how its distributing the files? Unsure what I'm doing wrong. I am pretty sure ffmpeg isn't to blame here at least

Comment: I think I've confirmed that nginx pushing the stream is the issue now to figure that portion out and see if I can figure out alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems YouTube does not like nginx. I found two solutions for this.

**Solution 1**

Add "meta copy;" to you nginx config as follow:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        application youtube{
            live on;
            meta copy;
            push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Modify nginx-rtmp-module/ngx_rtmp_codec_module.c and replace the line:

```
ngx_string("Server"),
```

with

```
ngx_string("xtradata"),
```

then recompile nginx.

Comment: Thanks sorry i didnt get to this earlier but it worked perfectly fine. I saw 0 problems doing that. thanks.